# Problem with gnome-control-center (Segmentation fault)

Tags: gnome, segmentation-fault, gnome-control-center

I've been trying to fix this issue for a couple of days. I'm using Ubuntu 17.10.

If I try to execute `gnome-control-center`, I get a "segmentation fault" message.

If I use `strace -e open gnome-control-center` I get the following:

```
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/cogl.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/cogl.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/cogl.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/cogl.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/cogl.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/cogl.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/cogl.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/cogl.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/cogl.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/cogl.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/cogl.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/cogl.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=NULL} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
Segmentation fault
```

I checked those paths and are empty, I have no idea why. I reconfigure local settings. If I run the same command with `sudo`, this happens:

[image]

Without being able to move from there. Log output is pretty much the same as the command without `sudo`.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: What desktop do you use? Have you reported bug by apport to launchpad?

Comment: Hey, I'm using gnome desktop. I haven't reported the problem as a bug, I'm not sure if it is. It happened after I tried to install some graphic card drivers.

Comment: Finally, I gave up and I installed 18.04 beta 2.